# Channel.html or other causing facebook-social-plugins to not interact wit Blog

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter4j

I am able to get the live stream on my blog at:   http://inclouddesign.com/facebook-live-stream
The login and logout seem to be working fine. I can add comments on my blog page and they show at Facebook. I think I have and issue with channel.html or somewhere in the code placement or structure. I am not able to add to Facebook and have it show on my blog page. If someone could help me through this issue it would help clarify this issue for future reference. I am fairly new to integrating these social widgets and such. I hope I am not out of line for asking here. You guys are pretty advanced for the most part. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: You need to clarify what is your problem and what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your issue. From view-source on your site:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";`

You need to replace `APP_ID` with your application ID.